# PHP:Javascript loading even after removal

Tags: javascript, php, netbeans, netbeans-8, yslow

I'm analyzing the running time of various components(CSS and JS) using Yslow tool on my PHP website(localhost).
On running Yslow, I get the following components:
[image: error]

I have already deleted the file 'bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.js' from my project, but still it's loading. Why so?

Comment: delete you cache and run it

Answer (score 2):

Load the website from within an Incognito window (CTRL+SHIFT+N).

You may very well wish to disable cache while Chrome's webdev tools are open, too.

See the guide here:
https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/settings